# How to pass multiple dict name to a proc

Tags: dictionary, tcl, proc

Let's say I don't know the name of the dict I have to pass, but I have list for it, so the setup looks like :

```
set mylist "dict_a dict_b"
dict set dict_a a 1
dict set dict_a b 2
dict set dict_b c 3
dict set dict_b d 4
```

But now I want to pass all my dict to a procedure (I still don't know the name of the dict, I know only the list of name). I would do something like :

```
proc test_dict {mylist} {
    foreach element $mylist {
        upvar 1 [subst $element] $element
    }
    foreach dict_ $mylist {
        puts " test of existence : [dict exists $dict_ a]"
    }
}
```

The answer of tcl is :

```
test of existence : 0
test of existence : 0
```

When called with :

```
test_dict $mylist
```

I should get 1 and 0 but not this. What is wrong in my proc ?

Comment: Please post the code you actually used, because what you showed here just gives a lot of errors.

Comment: Sorry, too much simplify, fixed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem is that you are making local variables with the same name as the arguments. That's a *tremendously* bad plan as it means that the procedure can't safely use any variable name at all. It's also usually a bad idea to use `subst` in situations like this, particularly as it is evaluating in the context of the procedure.

Instead, you should use a single loop and reuse the `upvar`-bound variable:

```
proc test_dict {mylist} {
    foreach element $mylist {
        upvar 1 $element theDict
        puts " test of existence : [dict exists $theDict a]"
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't think of any good design for handling an arbitrary number of variable bindings as you seem to be thinking of doing; they'll all be inefficient - involving at least one full lookup by name on every access - and many simpler-to-explain ones will be unsafe too.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `dict exists <dict> <key_name>` needs a literal dict or a dictionary value.   You are giving the dictionary variable name (not the value).

When you have a variable whose value is the name of another variable, but you need to get the value of that another variable, now there's two levels of interpolation.
An easy way to do multiple levels of interpolation is using the `set <varname>` command (with no second arg).

```
set first_var 5
set second_var "first_var"
set third_var "second_var"

tcl8.6.8> puts $third_var
second_var
tcl8.6.8> puts $$third_var
$second_var
tcl8.6.8> puts [set $third_var]
first_var
tcl8.6.8> puts [set [set $third_var]]
5
```

You can fix your proc like this:

```
proc test_dict {mylist} {
    foreach element $mylist {
        upvar 1 [subst $element] $element
    }
    foreach dict_ $mylist {
        puts " test of existence : [dict exists [set $dict_] a]"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be trying to solve the wrong problem.

You can achieve this with a nested dict instead of a list of dict names.

```
set my_dict [dict create]
dict set my_dict a a 1
dict set my_dict a b 2
dict set my_dict b c 3
dict set my_dict b d 4

proc test_dict {d} {
    foreach key1 [dict keys $d] {
        puts " test of existence (key1 = $key1): [dict exists $d $key1 a]"
    }
}


test_dict $my_dict
--> test of existence (key1 = a): 1
    test of existence (key1 = b): 0
```

With a nested dict, the first level of keys is essentially the same as your list of dict names.   The entire nested dict gets passed to the proc.